# String returned from oracle stored procedure to Java with '???'

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, oracle10g, weblogic

My code in Java calls stored procedure in Oracle DB and returns object with some fields.
When I find out the attributes from the Object - I have problem with the string. The string becomes '???' (3 questtion marks) and it not supposed to be that!
(integer returned OK)

I tested my stored procedure on the DB - It worked well.

I tested my Java code with small local main program that call to the DB - and it worked well. (The connection the the DB was direct with DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@......);  )

The problem came when I used my store procedure in my big project that connect to the DB with the weblogic.

Do you know how to get the right string from the DB when I work with the WebLogic?

Oracle code:

```
  PROCEDURE SearchOrder (InWoArr IN WoTab,
                     OutWoAccStat OUT WoAccStatTab) as
  outRec WoAccStatType;
  wo number(10);
  acc number(10);
  stat varchar2(2);
  begin
  OutWoAccStat := WoAccStatTab();
    for i in InWoArr.FIRST .. InWoArr.LAST loop
    OutWoAccStat.EXTEND;
      begin
       select work_order_number,account_number,' '
    into wo,acc,stat
    from table1
    where work_order_number=InWoArr(i);
    ....
    outRec := WoAccStatType(wo,acc,stat);
    OutWoAccStat(i) := outRec;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      outRec := WoAccStatType(InWoArr(i),0,' ');
      OutWoAccStat(i) := outRec;
  end;
end loop;
end SearchOrder;
```

//Array of 200

```
create or replace type poldev_dba.WoAccStatTab as VARRAY(200) of WoAccStatType
```

//The array type

```
create or replace type poldev_dba.WoAccStatType as object (work_order_number number(10), account_number number(10), wo_status varchar2(2))
```

//Java code:

```
              //Store Procedure Name
          CallableStatement cs = (CallableStatement) con.prepareCall("{ call spp.SearchOrder( ?, ? )}");                                                                                    

          //input:
          cs.setArray(1,woInput);

          //Output:
          cs.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.ARRAY,"WOACCSTATTAB");

          //Run the query...
          cs.execute();

          //Retrieve Array:
          woAccArray = (ARRAY)cs.getArray(2);
          woAccRecs = (Object[])woAccArray.getArray();

          int wo = 0;
          int acc = 0;
          String stat;

          for (int i = 0; i < woAccRecs.length; i++) {
              /* Since we don't know the type of the record, get it into STRUCT !! */
              STRUCT woAccRec = (oracle.sql.STRUCT)woAccRecs[i];
              /* Get the attributes - nothing but the columns of the table */
              Object[] attributes = woAccRec.getAttributes();

              /* attribute 0 - work order */
              wo = Integer.parseInt("" + attributes[0]);

              /* attribute 1 - account number */
              acc = Integer.parseInt("" + attributes[1]);

              /* attribute 2 - status */
              stat = (String) attributes[2]; 
              /*PROBLEM!!!! stat returned value '???'*/

              System.out.println("wo = " + wo + ",acc = " + acc +", status = "+stat);
```

Comment: What is the string supposed to be? I suspect an encoding and font issue when *displaying* the string. Try to debug your program and inspect the content of the String when returned from the stored-proc to know if it's really ???

Comment: The string is 'C' or 'O'. wasn't worked. I changed it to be '0' or ' ' - still not worked. (By the the small main with connection to the DB it eas worked and returned the 'C' and 'O')

Comment: Have you tried using NVARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR2?

Comment: Thanks ALL!!!

SWeko was right.
After I changed the variables from varchar2 to nvarchr2 is started work!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is elsewhere. Neither the Oracle DB nor the DB driver will replace a result column with `???`. Search the code of your product for this string to see why it is used.

Comment: I added my Java code. I not think the probelm in the code itself. By if I wrong - please correct me.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Try a different version of the Oracle JDBC driver; maybe it's a bug. If that doesn't work, replace the stored procedure with Java code. I always try to avoid stored procedures because they usually cause more problems than they solve. The main reason to use them is a) to hide DB specific code in a generic API (when you write a product that supports many databases) or b) when you need a feature that isn't supported by JDBC.

Comment: " I always try to avoid stored procedures because they usually cause more problems than they solve" - This is a poor comment and factually incorrect, stored procedures are extremely useful and the best method for sorting and limiting records to be returned from a database. Just because you have trouble with them doesn't mean they are to be avoided by all.

Comment: I do my sorting/limiting in SELECT queries... :-) As you can see, the comment fields are too small for deep discussions. My stance remains that most often stored procedures are abused and therefore dangerous.

Comment: My product will contain many calling to the DB, and maybe the client will want to change somthing in the future in the queries. Using store procedure will enable us to change the store procedure without change the code itself.

Comment: what about my other suggestions?